# h1 size differs in Div tag and section tag

Tags: html

I used H1 tag inside section tag and div tag, but h1 in section tag is small rather than h1 tag in div tag. Why?

```html
<section>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</section>
<h1>Hello World</h1>

<hr>

<div>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMAkv.png)

Comment: @Simone Rossaini, I didn't use any CSS in it, it's just a pure HTML

Comment: oh i didn't see snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers have default stylesheets. You can use the Developer Tools in a browser to inspect what styles are applied to the element.

Chrome's developer tools (for example) show:

> ```
> h1 {
>     display: block;
>     font-size: 2em;
>     margin-block-start: 0.67em;
>     margin-block-end: 0.67em;
>     margin-inline-start: 0px;
>     margin-inline-end: 0px;
>     font-weight: bold;
> }
> ```

and

> ```
> :-webkit-any(article,aside,nav,section) h1 {
>     font-size: 1.5em;
>     margin-block-start: 0.83em;
>     margin-block-end: 0.83em;
> }
> ```

So that is just how the developers of Chrome decided that a top level heading for a section should be rendered. Other browser developers will have probably made similar choices.

If you don't like it, write your own CSS to override it.